# use Broadcast Receiver to catch incoming call, onReceive not triggered?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to implement a simple BroadcastReceiver, it gets triggered when there's an incoming call. However, it seems onReceive is never triggered (I checked the LogCat very carefully, no output there), what was wrong? Tks
My class:

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "DEBUG";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Test loggiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiing!");

    }

}
```

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tung.le.android.receiver.phone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <receiver android:name=".MyPhoneReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                </action>

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You might test your reciever with a custom intent (perhaps your package name) first.  I think that will work.  Then we'll figure out why the PHONE_STATE intent is not being captured.  What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: hi David, tks for your suggestion, let me try. My version is 4.0.3

Comment: I hope your "MyPhoneReceiver" belongs to same package as of "tung.le.android.receiver.phone". If not, you will have to mention fully qualified name in manifest.

Answer (score 2):

you may need to add **android:enabled="true"** to your  tag in manifest, or you have to register it somewhere(e.g. the custom "YourApplication" class).

Answer (score 1):

the problem i experienced with this BroadcastReceiver solution, is that it can not trigger any calls that happen during an active call. when i talk with a person on the phone and someone calls me on the other line (and i accept that second call), there is actually no state that changed. the phone was offhook before and it remains offhook when i accept the second call.

the only solution i found so far is to register an observer for android.provider.Calls and then get the newest entry from it after each data change. if someone knows a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you registering your Receiver inside the code??. If not you will have to register your receiver in the manifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least have one activity in your project. Even if you finish it as soon as your app starts. It does not have to do anything, but it should starts at least once after installation.